# Regex with negative lookahead does work with zero or more preceeding whitespaces

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to understand how to make negative lookahead get executed after the series of `\s*:?\s*`. Right now it leads to unwanted matches, so I'm forced to use `\s*:?\s+`, but it doesn't cover some cases, e.g. `todo:match`.

Why do I need this: there is a todo comment check is source code analysis tool, I want to forbid usage of plain TODO comments, yet save the ability to write todo comments with linked tickets.

tl;dr: I want to make top examples unmatchable, yet match all bottom examples.

With star:
[image: With star]

Without star:
[image]

Source:
[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/T9b7N9sWpkGUwkc1)

```
(?ix)(?:fixme|todo)
\s*(?::|-|--)?\s+
(?!(?:(?:https|http):\/\/)?(?:www\.)?jira\.company\.com|\w+-\d+)
```

Test data:

```
TODO: AS-123 no match
todo: as-123 no match
fixme: https://jira.company.com/browse/AS-14965 no match
fixme: https://jira.company.com
fixme as-123 no match
todo:as-123 no match


todo match
todo        match
todo:match
todo :match
todo123
todo : match
todo: match
fixme: match
todo: match https://jira.company.com/
```

Comment: Can it be summarized as "forbid `todo/fixme: AA-111/https://something`" but "allow everything else"?

Comment: @NickReed it's inverse: forbid todo/fixme without url/ticket number.

Comment: Is your test data correct, then? Looks like you might have mixed up "match" and "no match".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **atomic groups**, the syntax is `(?>abc)`, it will forbid backtracking and "solidify" the `\s*:\s*` part the first time it's read by the regex engine.

`(?i)(todo|fixme)(?>\s*:?\s*)(?!http|\w+-\d+).*`

(I simplified the jira part, you can upgrade as needed)

Test on https://regex101.com/r/XNPtQS/1

Answer (score 1):

According to your comments, you want to allow only TODO statements with either a ticket number or a URL after them. This will, naturally, vary based on the structure of a ticket, but the following should work. The regexes are assuming you run them as case-insensitive.

This regex will match any *valid* todo: `(?:todo|fixme):?\s*(?:\w+\-\d+|https\S*)` [(Demo)](https://regex101.com/r/xt8ZaU/1/)

This regex will match any *invalid* todo: `(?:todo|fixme)\s*:?\s*(?!http\S*)(?!.*\w+\-\d+).*$` [(Demo)](https://regex101.com/r/xt8ZaU/4/) This uses lookarounds to make sure patterns of a ticket or URL are not present in the matches.

I'm not sure how `fixme: https://jira.company.com` and `todo: match https://jira.company.com/` are different, though - the second regex matches both.

Comment: It's different because i wanted to enforce some pattern. Thanks for an insight!